# GitLab: Exposing value generated from CI to UI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

For a lecture exercise at my university we have to write some code to solve a specific problem. Depending on how well our solution performs we get assigned a score. This is all achieved by running a single script that gives you a result which makes it perfect to run over CI.

Now this is a group project so I'd love to have some way to report the score back in the UI e.g. when performing merge requests so I don't have to scroll through the terminal output each time.

Usually one would use [artifact reports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#artifactsreports) for this. While the majority of these seem rather application specific (e.g. [junit test reports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#artifactsreportsjunit)), it looks like the [dotenv report](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) is the closest to what I want.

However I have found no way to expose the values directly in the UI. To my knowledge artifact reports should show up as widgets in the merge request view. However I found this not to be the case for me.

What would be a way to expose the value generated when running the CI to quickly see the score a specific branch or commit achieved?

Minified CI config of what I currently have

```yaml
image: python

run-test:
  script:
    # These are some logs generated by running the validation script
    - echo 1,2,3,4 > some_logs.csv
    # This is the result value I'd like to expose
    - echo result=12.34 > results.env

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - some_logs.csv
    reports:
      dotenv: results.env
```

and my university runs GitLab CE 13.7

Comment: Artifacts do not show up in the MR as widgets unless there is a specific feature for it. Since dotenv is used to store variables (as an artifact) for use in a later job, there's nothing pre-configured to display them in the MR by default. You can however take the results and add a comment to the MR using the API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#create-new-merge-request-note

Comment: Thanks for the info. I added an answer that uses the API to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Arty-chan's comment I updated my CI config to perform a POST request to GitLabs API.

Sample config:

```yaml
image: python

run-test:
  script:
    # These are some logs generated by running the validation script
    - echo 1,2,3,4 > some_logs.csv
    # This is the result value I'd like to expose
    - echo result=12.34 > results.env
    # Only perform POST if $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID is set
    - '[ -z "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID" ] && curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your API token>" "https://<instance url>/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID/notes?body=<message>"'

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - some_logs.csv
```

Note that all `<...>` need to be replaced with the appropriate values. Also note that `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` should be set on merge request but I wasn't able to achieve this consistently.

You will want to store `<your API token>` as a [CI variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/cicd_variables.html) to not leak it. Preferably use a [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) for this token.